# Two Divs - The centering and background for the second is not showing

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a webpage with three divs with the same background one on top left (as you look as the screen), one center right, and bottom left. I got the top left one working and copied the same code just changing the alignment. The second one just keeps putting the text at the top with no formatting. This is driving me nuts.

Thank you

```
  body {
   font-family:  Copperplate / Copperplate Gothic Light, sans-serif; 
  background-image: url(AAHbackground.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}


    #welcome { 
    padding:   5px; 5px;5px; 5px;      
  padding-left:   10px;      
   margin:             10x 10x 10x 10x;
   text-align:  left;
   color: #191919;
  background-image:    url(Divbackgrounds.jpg);
  background-repeat:   no-repeat; 
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
 p style = "float: left;"
 color : #731D1D;
h1, h2 {
  color:               #FF0066;
 }

    #leed {
      padding:   5px; 5px;5px; 5px;      
  padding-right:   30px;      
   margin:   10x 10x 10x 10x;
   text-align:  center;
   color: #191919;
  background-image:    url(Divbackgrounds1.jpg);
  background-repeat:   no-repeat
  position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px;
  width: 350px;
   color : #731D1D;
   h1, h2 {
  color:               #FF0066;
 }
```

Here's the problem. It seems to be moving the text and such but not attaching the background image to it. Here's the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="AAHStylesheet.css"/>
<title>Appalachian </title>

</head>

<body>

 <div id ="welcome">
<h1> Title </h1>

 <p>text text text</p>


</div>

<div id ="leed">
  <h1>Header/h1>

 <p>text .</p>

</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Please help :)

Kat

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at **[CSS background-position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)**